# Doubly linked list C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

To become more familiar with templates I attempted a doubly linked list implementation in C++. Is this a valid use for a template?

```
template <class T>
struct LinkedListNode {
    LinkedListNode<T>* m_previous;
    T m_data;
    LinkedListNode<T>* m_next;
};

template <class T>
class LinkedList {
public:
    LinkedList() {
        m_head = nullptr;
    }

    LinkedListNode<T>* m_head;

    void InsertEnd(T data);
    void InsertFront(T data);

};

template<class T>
inline void LinkedList<T>::InsertFront(T data)
{
    LinkedListNode<T>* insertedNode = new LinkedListNode<T>();
    LinkedListNode<T>* firstNode = m_head;

    if (!firstNode) {
        insertedNode->m_data = data;
        insertedNode->m_next = nullptr;
        insertedNode->m_previous = nullptr;
        m_head = insertedNode;
    }
    else {
        while (firstNode->m_previous != nullptr) {
            firstNode = firstNode->m_previous;
        }

        insertedNode->m_next = firstNode;
        insertedNode->m_previous = nullptr;
        insertedNode->m_data = data;

        firstNode->m_previous = insertedNode;

        m_head = insertedNode;
    }

}


template<class T>
inline void LinkedList<T>::InsertEnd(T data)
{
    LinkedListNode<T>* insertedNode = new LinkedListNode<T>();
    LinkedListNode<T>* lastNode = m_head;

    if (!lastNode) {
        insertedNode->m_data = data;
        insertedNode->m_next = nullptr;
        insertedNode->m_previous = nullptr;
        m_head = insertedNode;

    }
    else {
        while (lastNode->m_next != nullptr) {
            lastNode = lastNode->m_next;
        }


        lastNode->m_next = insertedNode;

        insertedNode->m_previous = lastNode;
        insertedNode->m_next = nullptr;
        insertedNode->m_data = data;
        m_head = insertedNode;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
LinkedList<int>* linkedList = new LinkedList<int>();
linkedList->InsertEnd(2);
linkedList->InsertEnd(5);
linkedList->InsertEnd(9);
linkedList->InsertFront(1);
linkedList->InsertEnd(10);

LinkedList<std::string>* stringList = new LinkedList<std::string>();
stringList->InsertFront("one");
stringList->InsertEnd("two");
stringList->InsertFront("three");
```

Ordering should be
**linkedList**
`1,2,5,9,10`
**stringList**
`three,one,two`

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](/help/on-topic) for more information. Specifically `InsertEnd` is faulty.  Have you tested this code?

Comment: @Edward Hi, thanks for the reply. I have tested the code and it runs fine for me and I have debugged this to ensure the ordering is correct, unless there are other cases that I have missed that produces incorrect results. I am not looking for help in fixing the code, but rather whether it is a correct usage for templates, and/or if anything could be done better.

Comment: Strengths of a doubly linked list are constant time front, back and random insertion/lookup/removal. The given implementation does neither of those operations in constant time (no lookup/removal at all, no random insertion, front and back insertion in linear time). (Just voicing my expectations when I hear "doubly linked list" - this doesn't mean your code is wrong, just that the implementation didn't match my expectations from the title).

Comment: @hoffmale Thanks for the reply. I agree the implementation is not finished, I was more focused on the approach, template usage, inline functions etc... and whether or not they were correct.

Comment: It would be useful if you augmented the question with the code you used to test.

Comment: @jjmcc I'm not sure it's worth a close vote but you should have finished implementing at least the fundamental features. removal and access are critical to a container and I'm not sure there is much to review without those.

Comment: @bruglesco I will finish the implementation then. Thank you

Comment: Just a recommendation: The node class is so closely linked to the list that it likely will not exist on its own - so you might prefer making node a nested class of list.

Comment: To simplify code, you might implement a circular list with a dummy element at the expense of 1 waste node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest thing I can say about your code is don't use raw pointers, start getting into the habit of using [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

> Smart pointers enable automatic, exception-safe, object lifetime management.

Answer (score 1):

**InsertFront**:

`m_head` should always point to the first node. So `while (firstNode->m_previous != nullptr)` loop looks unnecessary to me. If you're concerned about having `m_head` changed by the caller then i would make `m_head` private and provide getter method for that. Than you can merge if/else blocks as they are very similar.

**InsertEnd**:

Instead of iterating to find the last node every time (which makes it O(n)), you may maintain another pointer which always points to the last node. After that you may merge if/else blocks.

AFAIK following style of initializing class variables are more preferred.

```
LinkedList(): m_head(nullptr) {
}
```